# Pandas calculate the diff between all values in one group and the last value of the previous group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a pandas dataframe as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], 'idx': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3],
                     'category': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']}).set_index('idx')

Ouput:

      val category
idx              
9     30        a
8     40        a
7     50        b
6     60        b
5     70        c
4     80        c
3     90        c
```

I would like to add a new column with the difference between in each 'val' and the last 'val' of the previous category. The new column should look like this:

```
     category    diff  val
idx                       
9          a     nan     30
8          a     nan     40
7          b      10     50
6          b      20     60
5          c      10     70
4          c      20     80
3          c      30     90
```

Currently I do something like this:

```
temp_df = df.groupby('category')['val'].agg('last').rename('lastVal').shift()
df = df.merge(temp_df, on='date', how='outer', right_index=True)
df['diff'] = df['val'] - df['lastVal']
```

However it is quite slow. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can offload the mapping to pandas by setting category as the index first:

```
df2 = df.set_index('category')
df['diff'] = (
    df2['val'] - df.groupby('category')['val'].last().shift()).to_numpy()

df

     val category  diff
idx                    
9     30        a   NaN
8     40        a   NaN
7     50        b  10.0
6     60        b  20.0
5     70        c  10.0
4     80        c  20.0
3     90        c  30.0
```

Comment: I haven't seen you in pandas tag for some time :) +1

Comment: @AndyL., Interest has waned given recent drama on meta but I'm here from time to time because I enjoy contributing to the tag. Cheers :-)

Comment: ah, I guess it's the Monica scandal? I truly miss you, bro. Cheers.... :)

Comment: Many thanks! Doesn't df2 = `df.set_index('category')` create a copy of the dataframe? If so, would there potentially be a better way if the original dataframe is very large?

Comment: @user3607022 `df2 = df[['category', 'value']].set_index('category')` should be more efficient since that only keeps the columns you need. How large are we talking? Anything under 1M rows should not be a problem.

Comment: I see. Currently 1-2k columns and 500k rows so only keeping the relevant coumns sounds good. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is about twice the speed:

```
%%timeit

maxdf = df.groupby('category')['val'].last().shift()
df['diff'] = df['val'] - df['category'].map(maxdf.to_dict())

1.33 ms ± 20.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

vs your version

```
%%timeit

temp_df = df.groupby('category')['val'].agg('last').rename('lastVal').shift()
df2 = df.merge(temp_df, on='category', how='outer', right_index=True)
df2['diff'] = df2['val'] - df2['lastVal']

2.79 ms ± 83.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```